# Simple Reflections on Simple Roots

Tags: group-theory, reflection, root-systems, coxeter-groups

I have two related questions concerning simple reflections and simple roots. Let $\Phi$ be a root system for a reflection group $W$, let $\Pi \subset \Phi$ be a positive system, and let $\Delta$ be a simple system in $\Pi$. I know that if $\alpha \in \Delta$, then $s_{\alpha}(\Pi \setminus \{\alpha \}) = \Pi \setminus \{\alpha \}$.

My first question is, is it also true that $s_{\alpha}(\Delta \setminus \{\alpha\}) = \Delta \setminus \{\alpha \}$?
I feel like it should be true; maybe it has to do with the fact that positive systems contain unique simple systems.

My second question, which can be answer affirmatively if the above has an affirmative answer, is, if $\alpha \in \Delta$ and $\beta \in \Pi \setminus \Delta$, and $s_{\alpha}$ denotes ethe reflection of the hyperplane with normal vector $\alpha$, is it true that $ht(\beta) > ht(s_{\alpha}(\beta))$? I feel like it should be true, and I need it for something else I'm trying to prove, but I can't quite figure it out.

Allow me to recall what $ht(\beta)$ is, which denotes the height of $\beta$. First, recall that $\Delta$ is a basis for $\text{span } \Phi$ such that every $\beta \in \Phi$, $\beta$ is a linear combination of $\Delta$ with coefficients all of the same sign. Given $\beta \in \text{span } \Phi$, $\beta$ has a unique decomposition as $\beta = \sum_{\gamma \in \Delta} c_{\gamma} \gamma$, where $c_{\gamma} \in \Bbb{R}$. Then $ht(\beta) := \sum_{\gamma \in \Delta} c_{\gamma}$ is well-defined.

**EDIT** Not so sure the first question has a positive answer anymore. However, here are some thoughts on the second question. Let $\beta = \sum_{\gamma \in \Delta} c_{\gamma} \gamma$. By the reflection formula, we have

$$s_{\alpha}(\beta) = \beta - \frac{2 \langle \beta, \alpha \rangle}{||\alpha||^2} \alpha$$

$$= \sum_{\gamma} c_{\gamma} \gamma - b_{\alpha, \beta} \alpha$$

$$= \sum_{\ gamma \neq \alpha} c_{\gamma} \gamma + (c_{\alpha} - b_{\alpha, \beta}) \alpha$$
and therefore

$$ht(s_{\alpha}(\beta)) = \sum_{\ gamma \neq \alpha} c_{\gamma} + c_{\alpha} - b_{\alpha, \beta}$$

$$= ht(\beta) - b_{\alpha, \beta}$$
Now, if we knew or could argue that $b_{\alpha, \beta} > 0$, then we'd be done. Is this possible? In other words, if $\alpha \in \Delta$ and $\beta \in \Pi \setminus \Delta$, is it true that $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle > 0$?

Comment: In the first question, you mean to allow $\alpha$ to be an arbitrary positive root, correct?

Comment: I fail to understand why for questions like this people do not check the easiest examples. For your first question, the root system $A_2$ (and actually any other except the trivial $A_1$) shows the answer is no.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Checking examples seems to be a difficult thing for students. Possibly we still emphasize general theory too much.

Comment: For the second question, $G_2$ gives a counterexample. OP, if you think something is true for all root systems, do yourself a favour and before trying a proof, check it by inspection in $A_1, A_1\times A_1, A_2, B_2,$ and $G_2$. You can draw them all on scrap paper if needed, it's good to have them in your head anyway. Any two roots of any root system behave to each other like something from one of these.

Answer (score 1):

Neither question has an affirmative answer. Think about the root system of type $A_3$: this consists of the vectors
$$\pm \alpha_1 \quad \pm \alpha_2 \quad \pm \alpha_3 \quad \pm(\alpha_1+\alpha_2) \quad \pm(\alpha_2+\alpha_3) \quad \pm(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3)$$
where $$\alpha_1=(1,-1,0,0) \quad \alpha_2=(0,1,-1,0) \quad \text{and} \quad \alpha_3=(0,0,1,-1).$$ You may take $\Pi=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_1+\alpha_2,\alpha_2+\alpha_3,\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3\}$ and $\Delta=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\}$. Now compute: letting $s_1$ be the reflection for $\alpha_1$, check that it interchanges the first and second coordinates of a vector in $\mathbf{R}^4$. The highest root is $$\phi=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=(1,0,0,-1)$$ and we have
$$s_1(\phi)=(0,1,0,-1)=\alpha_2+\alpha_3.$$ Thus if you take $\beta=\alpha_2+\alpha_3$ the height of $s_1(\beta)$ is greater than that of $\beta$. The obvious generalization of this example shows that the answer to your second question is no for every irreducible root system except $A_1$, $A_2$ and $B_2$.

Comment: I think the answer is also yes for $B_2$, but indeed $G_2$ gives another counterexample, which (like all of $G_2$) is easy to visualize.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, thanks!

Comment: @Stephen Hmm...that's too bad. I'm trying to prove that if $\beta \in \Pi \setminus \Delta$, then $ht(\beta) > 1$. So, I know that if $\alpha \in \Delta$, then $ht(\alpha) = 1$; and also that there exists $w \in W = \langle s_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in \Delta \rangle$ such that $w \beta \in \Delta$, hence $ht(w \beta) = 1$. My thought was to argue that $ht(\beta ) > ht(w \beta) = 1$ by arguing $ht(\beta) > ht(s_{\alpha} \beta )$ for every $\alpha \in \Delta$...But I guess you're saying this won't work...Hmm.

Comment: @user193319 What definition of root system are you using? In the Bourbaki setup (which is what I always assume unless someone tells me otherwise) all roots are actually integer linear combinations of the simple roots. But I know that some people define "root systems" for non-crystallographic groups...

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Really? In $A_2$ the only choice for $\beta$ is the highest root, and in $B_2$ there are only two choices (and I don't think either one works).

Comment: @Stephen The definition I am using is as follows: $\Phi$ is a finite set of vectors in a real vector space $V$, then $\Phi$ is said to be a root system provided (1) $\Phi \cap \Bbb{R} \alpha = \{\pm \alpha \}$ for all and (2) $s_{\alpha} \Phi = \Phi$ for $\alpha \in \Phi$

Comment: @user193319 I see. I would usually call such a thing a "possibly non-crystallographic root system" if further context is lacking. The reason is that the crystallographic root systems are---by far---the more important, thanks to their relationship to Lie theory. I haven't ever thought about height for the non-crystallographic systems.

Comment: @user193319: Even in non-crystallographic root systems, what you want to prove there should be very easy. Am I mistaken, or is it clearly true that for $\alpha, \beta \in \Pi$ with $\alpha+\beta \in \Pi$, we have $ht(\alpha+\beta) = ht(\alpha)+ht(\beta)$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yeah, that seems right, but I don't quite see how it helps. We could write $ht(\beta + w \beta) = ht(\beta) + ht(w \beta) = ht(\beta) + 1$, but I don't know if $\beta + w \beta \in \Pi$ nor do I see how this helps in showing $ht(\beta) > 1$. Unless maybe its true that $\beta - w \beta \in \Pi$ and $h(\beta - w \beta ) > 0$...Could those be true?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Ah, okay. I know that given any $\beta \in \Phi$, there exists $w \in W$ such that $w \beta \in \Delta$, so choose $w \in W$ such that $\Delta \ni w(-\beta) = -w \beta$. Then, if we could argue that $\beta - w \beta \in \Pi$, I think we'd have $0 < ht(\beta - w \beta ) = ht(\beta ) - ht(w \beta)$ or $ht (\beta ) > 1$ (unless the second to last step is invalid). But I'm not sure how to argue that $\beta - w \beta \in \Pi$.

Comment: I don't see how that would work, but I admit my suggestion above is not as helpful as I thought either. You know what, I think Stephen answered your question here, and if you want, you can ask what you want as a new question. Just please if you do so make it explicit in that new question that we are talking about not necessarily crystallographic root systems.